# Windows 10 Update and Reset

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, reset

I received an old business desktop with Windows 7 Professional installed. I have attempted to uninstall as many unnecessary programs as I feel comfortable with, but a great deal of the 148GB hard drive is still taken up, and even though I am logged in as the admin, I am still lacking certain permissions for file removal. I figured the best thing to do was a factory reset, and start from scratch.

The issue here, is that I am currently lacking the original Windows install disk, and there is no previous hard drive state saved for me to do a basic revert to. I wanted to know if it would be possible to upgrade to Windows 10, and then factory reset from there, or will I still be limited by a lack of a physical disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can reset everything in Windows 10 without a disc. The options can be found in Settings → Update & Security → Recovery → under Reset This PC, click the Get Started button. The options look like this.

[image: Reset]

Comment: That worked perfectly. I had my files backed up just in case, but the system reset went exactly as anticipated. Thanks.

Comment: If I also want to remove the license key with slmgr should I do so _before_ running the reset above?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to reset your Windows 10 installation, as shown [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options).

Additionally, I would recommend backing up your $Windows.~BT and $Windows.~WS files on to a separate USB drive, so you can revert back to Windows 7 if something goes wrong.

Hope it works!